# jquery boxy, get element value on close/submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a file permissions dialog and am limited to the use of jquery and boxy.  No iframes, no popups.  The server side reading is taken care of, and so is submission.  My issue is i have elements inside the boxy and i've no idea how to retrieve their values.

Any help, or tutorial would be great. 
Have already read: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var r = []; // result array with values
$('#boxy input').each(function () {
    r.push(this.value);
});
$('#boxy textarea').each(function () {
    r.push($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: As it turns out my issue was with lack of knowledge, but this should work.